# CSS to mimic silverlight screen shot

Tags: html, css, silverlight

I'm pretty sure the question has been asked and answered, I don't know HTML and CSS well enough to know where or how to search.  Any help would be appreciated.

I have a community application built in Silverlight: http://www.scalerailsonline.com/default.aspx

Having finally decided to give Microsoft the chuck I'm rewriting it from scratch.  90% of is pretty easy.  I'm struggling with the HTML and CSS to accomplish the chat portion of the app.

I've marked up a screen shot to show what I'm trying to do.

[image]

The main goal is to create a scrollable container that expands and contracts to fit the available space.

First I want to have the web page expand or contract to fit in the browser window.

Second  Right column expands horizontally to fit the content and the bottom area expands vertically to fit the chat entry controls.

Once the page is fit to the browser and the space is committed to the right and bottom, i want the container to fit.  If the content in the container is too much (99% of the time it will be), then vertical scroll bar will display.

I have tried all kinds of combination of width/height: 100%.  But that just seems to make the areas big enough to fit the content, not constrain to a 100% of the browser.

I can set the div to "Height: 200%; Overflow: Scroll" to get the scroll bars.  But I just don't seem to be able to get the div to expand only to the available space.

Comment: Your site is not bad at all and you will have just as many (more?) issues with a HTML/css solution. I am curious why are you dumping the Microsoft stack after so much obvious effort?

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  I actually have a much bigger app in Silverlight/Azure and it's going to be rewritten as well.  Reason for change.  Primarly due to some real tough issues around SEO and monitization.  Crawlers don't deal with Silverlight based content well.  And AdSense won't work in a Silverlight environment either.  No support for Silverlight on tablets (IPad, and Android).  Last, my user community isn't adjusting to the lack of Right Click menus well.  I've included them where possible, but with 3rd party controls you can't get to all the places that you need to right click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First I want to have the web page expand or contract to fit in the browser window.

This can be achieved by setting the **margin** left and right to auto. Try this -

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh.  Right/Left is not a big issue.  It's setting it to limit to vertical browser height that is more of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:  There really isnt a good answer.  Resorting to java script resize event to set the hight of the box based on screen room - heights of screen elements.